# How to name Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, dockerfile, naming-conventions

I'm unsure of how to name Dockerfiles. Many on GitHub use `Dockerfile` without a file extension. Do I give them a name and extension; if so what? Or do I just call them `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 314, accepted):

[**Please read the full answer**]Don't change the name of the dockerfile if you want to use the autobuilder at hub.docker.com. Don't use an extension for docker files, leave it null.
File name should just be: (no extension at all)

```
Dockerfile
```

However, now you can name dockerfiles like,

```
test1.Dockerfile
$ docker build -f dockerfiles/test1.Dockerfile  -t test1_app .
```

or

```
Dockerfile.test1
$ docker build -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.test1  -t test1_app .
```

This will also work.

If you handle multiple files that live in the same context, you could use STDIN:

```
test1.Dockerfile
$ docker build -t test1_app - < test1.Dockerfile
```

Comment: What about when you have multiple Dockerfiles in the same directory?

Comment: @VisgeanSkeloru although a bit off a hassle you could put them in different directories if need be, no matter where I've looked it seem to be already established convention

Comment: @VisgeanSkeloru Don't have multiple Dockerfiles in the same directory. The containing directory becomes the [context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage) for the `docker build` command, which means that each image will be needlessly rebuilt if another image's dockerfile is changed.

Comment: @Thomas sometimes you need to place multiple Dockerfiles in the same directory in order to share common files across separate containers, because docker context doesn't allow to access "../some-common-stuff"

Comment: Does the "D" have to be capitalized or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Hello Everyone, command to run such named Dockerfile is: docker build -t name/name -f test.Dockerfile . dot at the end is important!

Comment: I rolled back the answer to an earlier revision because it included a blatant copy from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48879266/6707985).

Comment: You could also use the STDIN to pass the file as an standard input: `docker build - < rarename.dockerfile` and should work

Comment: @Aosi feel free to update the answer.

Comment: Mind documenting where some of these recommendations are sourced from? Are these just gut feelings, or are they substantiated by any official best practice guides, special IDE support, or something else?

Comment: If I run `docker build -f something.Dockerfile .` (where `something.Dockerfile` is a file in the CWD) it just opens a new terminal window then closes it immediately again, and seemingly no image is built.

Comment: @Aosi: that only works for dockerfiles which don't need a build context (see https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#pipe-dockerfile-through-stdin), therefore I cannot make sense of your sentence `If you handle multiple files that live in the same context, you could use STDIN`.

Answer (score 174):

`dev.Dockerfile`, `test.Dockerfile`, `build.Dockerfile` etc.

On VS Code I use `<purpose>.Dockerfile` and it gets recognized correctly.

Comment: Recognized correctly on IntelliJ Idea Community 2020.2 as well!

Comment: to build image:  docker build . -f dev.Dockerfile

Comment: How do you build with that? If I run `docker build -f foo.Dockerfile .` it just opens another terminal window (on top of the one I'm using) then closes it straight away and no image is built, with no error either. Weird. This is in Powershell, Windows.

Comment: @Mitya, not sure. If it helps, my build command is `docker build -f base.Dockerfile .` in linux and it works. Does a normal build command work for you `docker build -f Dockerfile .` ?

Comment: Any time I specify `-f <name>` I get this weirdness with the new terminal window. The solution I worked out in the end was to use a docker-compose.yml and specify the Dockerfile in there via `build > dockerfile: foo.Dockerfile`

Answer (score 80):

I know this is an old question, with quite a few answers, but I was surprised to find that no one was suggesting the naming convention used in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/#file):

> ```
> $ docker build -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.debug -t myapp_debug .
> $ docker build -f dockerfiles/Dockerfile.prod  -t myapp_prod .
> ```
>
> The above commands will build the current build context (as specified by the `.`) twice, once using a debug version of a `Dockerfile` and once using a production version.

In summary, if you have a file called `Dockerfile` in the root of your build context it will be automatically picked up. If you need more than one `Dockerfile` for the same build context, the suggested naming convention is:

```
Dockerfile.<purpose>
```

These dockerfiles could be in the root of your build context or in a subdirectory to keep your root directory more tidy.

Comment: It makes sense too because like this, when sorted alphabetically and sitting alongside other files in a directory, all Dockerfiles are grouped together.

Comment: That reasoning can be applied to all files, yet by convention we have extentions, i.e. types of files,  as suffix to the filename.

Comment: The problem is that `.purpose` is now the extension of your file, which might confuse the system, text-editor or IDEs. `<purpose>.Dockerfile` has the advantage of always having `.Dockerfile` as extension

Comment: Read the docs you linked and it does include references to both naming formats such as using `.Dockerfile` as the extension. From the official docs: `For example, running docker build -f myapp.Dockerfile . will first look for an ignore file...`. From here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file

Comment: Having that capital "D" in the extension just doesn't sit right with me. :)

Comment: you can use sort by extension to group together all Dockerfiles if it is `<purpose>.Dockerfile`

Answer (score 40):

I think you should have a directory per container with a Dockerfile (no extension) in it. For example:

```
  /db/Dockerfile
  /web/Dockerfile
  /api/Dockerfile
```

When you build just use the directory name, Docker will find the Dockerfile. e.g:

```
docker build -f ./db .
```

Comment: Will it build 3 containers from your example?

Comment: @alvas Yes it will

Comment: It is not good enough many cases. Docker can not see files up. For example target, build, etc.

Comment: Can we run this 3 docker file at single time using docker-compose command then?

Comment: but this is why docker compose is good to use instead IMO. Then it's very flexible how you wanna structure or locate your actual dockerfile(s)

Comment: This method has the advantage of passing a smaller build context.  If you have a lot of content in the main folder, passing "." as build context - when using dev.dockerfile, etc. -  may slowdown building every image as all context is always passed to each image...

Comment: @Cyva: not true. The Dockerfile directory and the build context path are independent of each other.

Comment: I tried this structure years ago and it just made it a pain to search for Dockerfiles as they all had the same name

Answer (score 26):

I have created two Dockerfiles in same directory,

```
# vi one.Dockerfile
# vi two.Dockerfile
```

to build both Dockerfiles use,

```
# docker build . -f one.Dockerfile
# docker build . -f two.Dockerfile
```

Note: you should be in present working directory..

Answer (score 23):

> Do I give them a name and extension; if so what?

You may name your Dockerfiles however you like. The default filename is `Dockerfile` (without an extension), and using the default can make various tasks easier while working with containers.

Depending on your specific requirements you may wish to change the filename. If you're building for multiple architectures, for example, you may wish to add an extension indicating the architecture as the [resin.io](https://resin.io) team has done for the HAProxy container their [multi-container ARM example](https://github.com/resin-io-projects/multicontainer-getting-started):

```
Dockerfile.aarch64
Dockerfile.amd64
Dockerfile.armhf
Dockerfile.armv7hf
Dockerfile.i386
Dockerfile.i386-nlp
Dockerfile.rpi
```

In the example provided, each Dockerfile builds from a different, architecture-specific, upstream image. The specific Dockerfile to use for the build may be specified using the [`--file, -f` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) when building your container using the command line.

Comment: I like using an extension to indicate architecture (or whatever). Unlike some other answers, all the Dockerfiles are dead simple to find in a big, cluttered directory; they naturally sort together.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use the autobuilder at hub.docker.com, it *has to be* `Dockerfile`.  So there :)

Comment: I believe the context of the question was more broad. Perhaps you could include additional information for individuals not using _autobuilder_ to make this answer more complete.

Answer (score 20):

It seems this is true but, personally, it seems to me to be poor design.  Sure, have a default name (with extension) but allow other names and have a way of specifying the name of the docker file for commands.

Having an extension is also nice because it allows one to associate applications to that extension type.  When I click on a Dockerfile in MacOSX it treats it as a Unix executable and tries to run it.

If Docker files had an extension I could tell the OS to start them with a particular application, e.g. my text editor application.  I'm not sure but the current behaviour may also be related to the file permisssions.

Comment: I prefer using <name>.Dockerfile in such a scenario. Works well with Jetbrains IDEs as well.

Answer (score 5):

`Dockerfile` is good if you only have one docker file (per-directory). You can use whatever standard you want if you need multiple docker files in the same directory -
if you have a good reason. In a recent project there were AWS docker files and local dev environment files because the environments differed enough:

```
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.aws
```

Comment: I've seen this method used for specifying architectures as well. For example, placing a `Dockerfile.armv7hf` next to a `Dockerfile.i386`.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 main Dockerfile naming conventions:

**1. Using a default Dockerfile:**

Keeping it simple, this approach suits standalone, and well-defined projects.

```
$ docker build -f ./Dockerfile.Dockerfile .
```

**2. Using a custom Dockerfile:**

Keeping it custom, this approach familiarises the developer with the application context, eases file manipulation and helps with debugging, particularly when having multiple dockerfiles.

```
$ docker build -t <containername> . -f <mycustomdockerfile>.Dockerfile
```

---

**Gentle Reminder:**

These conventions are equally applicable for common docker image building commands such as 'docker image build' and 'docker-compose build'.

Answer (score 3):

Dockerfile (custom name and folder):

```
   docker/app.Dockerfile
   docker/nginx.Dockerfile
```

Build:

```
   docker build  -f ./docker/app.Dockerfile .
   docker build  -f ./docker/nginx.Dockerfile .
```