# Dockerfile naming: .dockerfile vs Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, naming-conventions

I'm new to Dockerfile nomenclature and have noticed a few different examples of dockerfiles in repos throughout my org including the following types:

- Dockerfile
- Dockerfile.build
- .dockerfile

Is there somewhere I can find a detailed explanation for the different use cases and purposes of each?

Comment: I don't think its a hard and fast rule to name dockerfile in any way, the build command can be used to build docker image using any file name

Comment: I'd stick with the default, `Dockerfile`, unless you have a reason to use any other name.

Comment: The Docker docs themselves also recommend putting each `Dockerfile` in its own directory so you can keep the default filename.  Examples: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/ and https://github.com/docker/labs.  In [moby](https://github.com/moby/moby), it looks like they use a different convention of `Dockerfile[.<special case>]`.  I have also seen `example.dockerfile` in the wild, though this can be confusing because then all of the Dockerfiles in a given project aren't grouped together when listed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to name Dockerfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077543/how-to-name-dockerfiles)

Answer (score 2):

This is the `docker build` command, see [the official docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for details.

```
docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -
```

The `docker build` command expects the file name to exactly be `Dockerfile`. So, in that case, you can simply do

```
docker build .
```

In other cases, you have to specify the full name as

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.build .
```

So the file name has nothing to do with the container itself. Those different names are for your own convenience.